# Android phone as a Game Controller in PC

Tags: c#, android, controller, driver

This is about my thesis again, How can I substitute my Android phone into a Game Controller (specifically a steering wheel) in a PC? Do I need to use game controller drivers? and how can I use these drivers if i need one?. I decided I will use C# for my PC server. Thank You.

Comment: glovepie + PPJoy + server conected to android device via BT or WiFi (fx look here http://forum.1cpublishing.eu/showthread.php?t=25897) or http://code.google.com/p/agamepad/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. If you find a particular response helpful please vote it up. If a response has answered your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**On Android Side**

You can use Accelerometer coordinates for this purpose. It can easily act as an steering wheel. You will just have to read and map the coordinates accordingly. Behind the scene you can send data to a server i.e. your PC. This server will then send commands to the game

**On PC**

You can find the game window using this method http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindowEx

Then you can send keyboard keys to game window using this
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html

Comment: Im sorry i'm a newbie at C# i just decided to use it because I have a bit of experience of socket programming in C in linux. I cant understand the codes in your links. can you give me a summary on how can I use the game window and keyboard keys?. Thank You and sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: Basically method belongs to Windows API. Through windows API you can find and control the Game Window (Window/Screen in which your game will be running) Once you have found the window (in code) you can send it keys (like you do with your keyboard left, right ...)  Take a look at this tutorial and Google for more http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsAPIsFromCS.aspx

Comment: oh. Okay. I will research further for this and will give you updates about it. Thank You for your help :)